# Stacking cylinders

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have three identical, vertical, cylindrical tanks each with a diameter of 1040mm. They need to be crated. What is the minumum internal area of the rectangular crate required ?

Comment: Would you like to put all the three in one crate, or each crate will be put in a different crate?

Comment: @Kannappan: It seems pretty clear to me that all three are to go in one crate. The question wouldn't make much sense otherwise.

Comment: @Mike: Your question is needlessly complicated. Vertical tanks? 1040mm? What you want to know is, what is the smallest rectangle that can contain three non-intersecting disks of radius 1?

Comment: @TonyK It wouldn't as you mention. But it is possible that OP is lost somewhere even in such a case.

Answer (score 3):

There are two configurations you might think about.  You could put the three cylinders in a line, needing $1040 \times (3\cdot 1040)=3244800 \text{ mm}^2$  Alternately, you can put two next to each other and the third beside them.  This puts the centers at the corners of an equilateral triangle  of side $1040$.  The two next to each other force the width of the rectangle to be $2\cdot 1040=2080$.  The height is the height of the triangle, $1040 \frac{\sqrt 3}2$ plus $1040$, so the total area is $2080 \cdot 1040 (1+ \frac{\sqrt 3}2 )\approx 403659 \text{ mm}^2$

Comment: There may be a third configuration. See http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/ciranima/ (and then click on it to see it move).

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  Good point.  They are again on an equilateral triangle, but there looks to be a better bounding rectangle.